# Import-Csv TrimEnd Column Header

Tags: csv, powershell

I need import a CSV and run it through a `foreach` loop. I want to trim the end on the column header `DeviceName` to avoid any potential issues. I have tried the following but it is not working as expected.

```
$Import = Import-CSV $csv

foreach ($i in ($import.DeviceName).TrimEnd())
{do something}
```

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: What _is_ happening and what do you _expect_? Are you just trying to change the first line where the header is located? or all the properties associated to the DeviceName. `$import.DeviceName` is an array and not a string

Comment: You missing closing parenthesis.

Comment: Are you worried that the header itself has trailing whitespace, or the data under that header has trailing whitespace?

Comment: I am expecting that the column header (deviceName) be trimmed of any trailing spaces as it is looped. So the result inside the loop would be $i.DeviceName (no spaces). We receive the csv from another team and sometimes it is DeviceName (no trailing spaces) and others it is DeviceName (trailing space). Since we are keying off that DeviceName I am trying to code where it doesn't matter what we receive.

Comment: Yes, that the header has trailing whitespace.

Comment: Do you need to write back to file or just continue processing with the trimmed code?

Comment: Yes, at the end I will be exporting the results back into a new csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to change both the header and the content in the column for `devicename` which has spaces I have come up with this forgiving code.

```psh
$csvData = import-csv $csv

$properties = $csvData[0].psobject.Properties.name
$csvHeader = "`"$(($properties | ForEach-Object{$_.Trim()}) -join '","')`""
$deviceHeader = $properties -match "DeviceName"

$csvHeader
$csvHeader | Set-Content $file
$csvData | ForEach-Object{
    $_.$deviceHeader = ($_.$deviceHeader).trim()
    $_
} | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Add-Content $file
```

What this does is read in the CSV like normal. Parse the property names of the object in the order they appear. We find the one that has `DeviceName` no matter how many spaces (if there is more that one you could have a problem). Keep that so we can use it to call the correct property of each "row".

Export the new cleaned header to the file. Then we go through each "row" removing all the leading and trailing space from the `DeviceName`. Once that is done write back the CSV to the original file.

Comment: I changed my variable names as they conflicted with yours. Should be fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be to tell the other team to fix their generation procedure. However, if for some reason that's not an option, I'd recommend pre-processing the file before you import it as a CSV.

```psh
$filename = 'C:\path\to\your.csv'

(Get-Content $filename -Raw) -replace '^(.*DeviceName)[ ]*(.*)', '$1$2' |
  Set-Content $filename
```

Reading the file as a single string (`-Raw`) and anchoring the expression at the beginning of the string (`^`) ensures that only the column title is replaced.

For large input files you may want to consider a different approach, though, since the above reads the entire file into memory before replacing the first line.

```psh
$infile  = 'C:\path\to\input.csv'
$outfile = 'C:\path\to\output.csv'

$firstLine = $true
Get-Content $infile | % {
  if ($firstLine) {
    $_ -replace '(DeviceName)[ ]*', '$1'
    $firstLine = $false
  } else {
    $_
  }
} | Set-Content $outfile
```

Thinking about it some more and taking inspiration from a comment to [@Zeek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31059692/1630171)'s answer, you could also extract the headers first and then convert the rest of the file.

```psh
$infile  = 'C:\path\to\input.csv'
$outfile = 'C:\path\to\output.csv'

$header = (Get-Content $infile -First 1) -split '\s*,\s*'

Get-Content $infile |
  select -Skip 1 |
  ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $header |
  Export-Csv $outfile -NoType
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this all you're trying to do? This will give you a collection of objects imported from your csv file but trim the end of the DeviceName property on each object.

```
$items = Import-CSV -Path $csv
$items.ForEach({ $_.DeviceName = $_.DeviceName.TrimEnd() })
```

Comment: You could do either .ForEach({}) or ForEach-Object (depending on the version of PowerShell you are using.

Comment: I just tried it. Never used that way before. I assumed it was a typo in error until I looked at the rest of it.

Comment: If all you need to do is trim the header then you can do Import-Csv -Path $csv -Header "Col1,"Col2","Col3",DeviceName,"Col4".

Comment: .ForEach({}) was introduced in PowerShell v3 and has faster performance vs ForEach-object. http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/10/22/foreach-and-where-magic-methods/

Comment: Not having any luck with that code, here are my results: `PS C:\> $import."devicename " = 
test123`
`PS C:\> $import | % { $_.DeviceName = $_.DeviceName.TrimEnd() }
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.At line:1 char:15
+ $import | % { $_.DeviceName = $_.DeviceName.TrimEnd() }
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull`